# Get turning point, minima and maxima in hand drawn graph, iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, curve-fitting

I want to build an app where the user can draw a graph with his hand oder with a pen. The app should transform the sketch into a real graph(simple curves and lines, curve fitting) and find the extremal values of the graph.
What would be the simplest way to achieve that? Are there any libraries that can do that? It has to work on an iPad or an Android Tablet?

Are there any good keywords for that problem, that can help me researching on a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide more detail about whether do you want solution in native libraries or cross platform libraries like Xamarin,Cordova etc..

Comment: This is either way too broad (if you don't want to use libraries) or [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (if you're asking for libraries) For android and if you're good at maths: it may be worth looking at [PathInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/PathInterpolator.html) to get a function out of the sketch.

Comment: I would prefer a native solution for either android or iOS. @Raviprakash

Comment: If there is a nice library that can help me out, I would be glad to use it. Thanks, I'll give it a look! @0X0nosugar